# I dont understand this problem

Tags: calculus, integration, learning, question-verification

How is the answer to this not -6? Please solve this without U substitution because I need to know what I did wrong to get a negative answer. I did interval (B) - (A) as you should

$$\int_{-21}^0  \dfrac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{~4-x~}} ~$$

[Problem-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikWVp.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The integrand is positive, so the integral should be positive. If that answers the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it not -6?

The negative sign changes the direction of the integral's bounds.

Lets do it in two substitution steps. Use the substitution $v:=4-x$ and then $u:=\surd v$ .

$$\begin{align}\int_{-21}^0 \dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{~4-x~}} &= \int_{4-21}^{4-0}-\dfrac{\mathrm d v}{\surd v}&~:~&\mathrm d v =-\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\int_{4}^{25}\dfrac{\mathrm d v}{\surd v}\\[2ex]&=\int_{\surd 4}^{\surd 25} 2~\mathrm d u &~:~&\mathrm du=\dfrac{1}{2\surd v}\mathrm d v \\[2ex]&= 2~(5-2)\\[2ex]&=6 \end{align}$$

Or "without" substitution

$$\begin{align}\int_{-21}^0 \dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{~4-x~}} &= \int_{x=21}^{x=0} -2\mathrm d \surd(4-x)\\[2ex] &= -2(\surd(4-0)-\surd(4+21))\\[2ex]&=6\end{align}$$

Comment: where did the negative 2 come from?

∫x=0x=21−2d√(4−x)

Comment: $\qquad\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d \surd(4-x)}{\mathrm dx}&=\dfrac{\mathrm d(4-x)}{\mathrm d x}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d \surd(4-x)}{\mathrm d(4-x)}\\&={-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2\surd(4-x)}\end{align}$

Comment: what does "d" stand for?

Comment: Leibniz's notation